# Highcharts - stacked column - order series index dynamically for each category

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a scenario where i am drawing a stacked column chart, currently stuck at a point where i need to order the series in a specific order in case of multiple data points on the same day. The issue is, the series order can be different for each day - I have the code and example below -

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 
    'gray'
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -30,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) 
      || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false
 },
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: 
                 {point.stackTotal}'
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && 
                   Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Mary',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Kevin',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/arj_ary/4kz7rdpn/2/

Requirement: In the above JSFiddle, for each category i want the lowest datapoint to show up at the top. So for Apples i want Mary at the top since it has a value of 2. Similarly for Oranges and Pears.

Can this be accomplished? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The best I could do was to get a total for each person and then sort the data, but I do not think that is what you are asking for. I think you want each column to be large to smallest with largest at the bottom.

Comment: sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffld/kseqow0m/3/

Comment: @jeffld good try, but yeah doesn't work for me. I need the series itself to be ordered with the least data for that category always on the top. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using this approach:

1. create a function which sort columns:

- loop through points and group them by category (apples, oranges etc)
- loop through each group of points and sort the group by y value
- loop through points in each group and set a newly calculated y position using `SVGElement.attr` method (point.graphic is an SVGElement instance). Do the same for `point.dataLabel` and set a new position to `point.tooltipPos` array (otherwise tooltip will be placed wrongly).

```js
function sortColumns() {
  var chart = this,
    pointsByCat = {},
    zeroPixels,
    bottomYPositive,
    bottomYNegative,
    shapeArgs;

  chart.series.forEach(function(serie) {
    serie.points.forEach(function(point, index) {

      if (pointsByCat[point.category] === undefined) {
        pointsByCat[point.category] = [];
      }

      pointsByCat[point.category].push(point);
    });
  });

  Highcharts.objectEach(pointsByCat, function(points, key) {
    zeroPixels = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0) - chart.plotTop;
    bottomYPositive = bottomYNegative = zeroPixels;

    points.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.y - a.y;
    });

    points.forEach(function(point) {
      if (point.series.visible) {
        if (point.shapeArgs.y < zeroPixels) {

          // Positive values
          point.graphic.attr({
            y: bottomYPositive - point.shapeArgs.height
          });

          point.dataLabel.attr({
            y: bottomYPositive - point.shapeArgs.height / 2 - point.dataLabel.height / 2
          });

          point.tooltipPos[1] = bottomYPositive - point.shapeArgs.height;
          bottomYPositive = bottomYPositive - point.shapeArgs.height;
        } else {

          // Negative values
          point.graphic.attr({
            y: bottomYNegative
          });

          point.dataLabel.attr({
            y: bottomYNegative + point.shapeArgs.height / 2 - point.dataLabel.height / 2
          });

          point.tooltipPos[1] = bottomYNegative;
          bottomYNegative = bottomYNegative + point.shapeArgs.height;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

2) set above function as a callback to `chart.events.load` and `chart.events.redraw` events:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: sortColumns,
      redraw: sortColumns
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1704phc8/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: What is the logic behind selecting the last point's shapeArgs in the pointsByCat above?
This line : - shapeArgs = points[points.length - 1].shapeArgs;

There's a flaw in the above logic, the columns start floating around because the logic to set the new " y " and " bottomY " is not clear.

Comment: The last point is selected because points are sorted and rendered in new positions starting from the last one which is on top of the stack. Could you reproduce this issue?

Comment: So what should i change in the above logic if the columns need to be sorted by another property and not by ' y' value ? Like say they need to sort by calendarDate? In that case, i can change the sort function to sort by calendarDate but the shapeArgs is fetched of the last element in the array ?

Comment: Yes, it is fetched of the last element because points are rendered from the last point. The whole stack of points has the same height only order is changed no matter how the columns are sorted.